# Docker asking for login in windows 10

Tags: docker

I issued a command "docker build -t httpd ."from bash with preconfigured docker file having 
FROM httpd.latest .

Once command is executed and after step 1 it says "pull access denied for httpd.latest, repository does not exist or may required docker login.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , image which you are using might not exixts in public dockerhub

First search image using

```
docker search httpd
```

If you can find that then you need to create on

https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/c14a031c014aa2219aea2e73786f577300756f0b/2.2/Dockerfile

In your dockerfile use

```
FROM httpd
```

not latest,

docker will pull latest image if tag is not specified or use specific version

Comment: try this not sure if it works, create account in dockerhub which is free, then use "docker login " provide username/password. Then try to pull

Comment: Like docker login "ABC/123"?

Comment: just docker login,  it will ask for username first then password

Comment: Attaching the image when used with docker login. USE HTTPS goo.gl/e1NM6E